# PowerBI to ADLS Gen2 With Firewall issue

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

We have an interesting issue that has cropped up recently. This connectivity used to work and now fails. We have a PowerBI report that connects to ADLS Gen2 directly. The ADLS has a firewall configured to prevent unwanted access. Up until recently, the Power Query engine in PowerBI online would present itself from the PowerQuery IP range **20.42.4.200/30** as defined here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Now, see logs below, Power Query / PowerBI is presenting itself as an internal IP. ALDS wont let me whitelist an internal IP range and there is no network configured that I know of that we can peer to.

I have checked and changed firewall settings (dropping the firewall allows access fine - so it is not an auth issue), PowerBI tenant level settings etc and cant understand why this routing is now happening.

In short, the question is, how do I allow PowerBI service to connect to an ADLS Gen 2 which has a firewall configured? This used to work fine, I cant fathom what has changed and why the refresh from PowerBI online is presenting as if it is from an internal subnet.

** *Log Entry from the datalake logs* **

2.0;2021-10-06T02:37:41.0000918Z;ListFilesystemDir;IpAuthorizationError;403;1;1;authenticated;;;blob;"https://.dfs.core.windows.net/prod?resource=filesystem&recursive=true&directory=models%2FFacts%2FInvoiceLineItem.parquet";"//prod";4216abcd-001f-0054-6e5b-ba3870000000;0;**10.2.0.230**;2018-06-17;492;0;195;0;0;;;"gzip, deflate";Monday, 01-Jan-01 00:00:00 GMT;;"Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225)";;"eac70f78-91f9-266b-bacc-ba6b20752fe2";;;;;;;;

Answer (score 0):

Add inbound security rule not for specific IP address or range, but for a service tag (`PowerQueryOnline` in this case). Service tags are managed by Microsoft and represent the IP addresses used. This reduces the complexity of the firewall security rules.

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to add a service tag to an ADLS Gen 2 firewall, but I did create an inbound security rule for the service tag on the network security group of the VNET, and made sure the VNET has a subnet that that connects to the ADLS Gen 2 but still no luck - what am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to tell. It looks like you are following the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network). Good luck!